# Week, month, day, year predictors in the same regression

Tags: time-series, forecasting, feature-selection, seasonality, trend

Say you have a response $y$ which, over time, clearly goes in some direction. Up, maybe.

Now, you have to pick some predictors in a regression equation $y \sim x$.

Obviously you can take a look at plots and judge what predictor would work the best. If, for example, there's a lot of clustering despite an upwards trend, then it might be that there's a "month" or "year" effect, while if the trend is rapid on even the smallest intervals, then "week" or "day" might be better.

**However,** can I solve this problem by first just fitting $y \sim week + day + year + month$, and then see what I can remove, one by one, using AIC?

Comment: Since "week," "day," "year," and "month" are all measures of time, they would appear to be redundant.  Could you please explain exactly what these are and how you distinguish them from each other?